# Converge Duplicate Rows in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like below.

```
SuppID   AreaID     SuppNo   SupName    SupPrice
------------------------------------------------
1        3            526    ANC         100 
1        3            985    JTT         200
3        4            100    HIK         300
```

In the above table. for same SuppID(1) and same AreaID(3), different SuppNo are there (526 & 985).

I'd like to make the first two rows into a single row with SuppNo field as blank when this scenario happens.

Also my output result should display all the columns.

Any Help?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the underlying data in the table, or just perform this merge when *selecting* this data for a particular query?

Comment: I want this change while doing a Select Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple aggregate really, using COUNT to determine what to do with SuppNo

```
SELECT
    SuppID, AreaID,
    COUNT(*) AS DupeCount, --added after comment
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(SuppNo) END
FROM
    (
    VALUES (1, 3, 526), (1, 3, 985), (3, 4, 100)
    ) AS MyTable (SuppID, AreaID, SuppNo)
GROUP BY
    SuppID, AreaID;
```

Comment: @Osceria: Please accept this answer then with the tick on the left. Thanks

Comment: If I need the count where SuppID and AreaID are same, how to get it?

Comment: @Osceria: add COUNT(*) as an output

Comment: I tried to get that count in a variable. But it's showing error

Comment: If i have many columns in the table but the output resultset should display rows with all columns removing the duplicates based on a single column as u replied above?